# Is it possible to have lazy behaviour in enum's function?

Tags: swift

Swift provides a very handy `lazy var`

However, I was wondering, can we achieve similar lazy functionality for `Enum`'s function?

For instance,

```
class Utils {
    static let userDataDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
}

enum UserDataDirectory : String {
    case Extract = "extract"
    case Camera = "camera"
    case Mic = "mic"
    case Attachment = "attachment"
    case Recording = "recording"
    case RestoreAttachment = "restore_attachment"
    case RestoreRecording = "restore_recording"

    func get() -> URL {
        return Utils.userDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent(self.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Is it ever possible, to turn `enum UserDataDirectory`'s `get` function to have lazy evaluation behaviour.

Or, is there a way to avoid evaluation of `appendingPathComponent` every-time, since `Utils.userDataDirectory` and `self.rawValue` is constant?

Comment: The question makes no sense. A function like your `get()` is _already_ "lazy": it is not evaluated until it is called, which is exactly what "lazy" means.

Comment: Lazy in the sense, `appendingPathComponent` will be executed only at most 1 time, even `get()` is being called N time.

Comment: matt's point is that Swift used a confusing and inconsistent meaning of the word "lazy." In the "lazy var" sense it means what some languages call "memoized." The Swift collection method ".lazy" matches what many other languages (and most CS discussions) mean by "lazy," which is "evaluated on demand."

Comment: Well, it can never be executed only 1 time, because there are seven cases. And as I said in my comment on Rob's answer, you're describing memoization, not laziness.

Answer (score 1):

You just mean that you want a lazily-evaluated static value. That's straightforward; add a static cache:

```
enum UserDataDirectory : String {
    // ...

    // Define storage
    private static var urls: [Self: URL] = [:]

    func url() -> URL {
        // Check the cache
        if let url = Self.urls[self] {
            return url
        } else {
            // Compute and cache
            let url = Utils.userDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent(self.rawValue)
            Self.urls[self] = url
            return url
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the word here is "memoize", not "lazy".

Comment: Yes, but Swift chose to confusingly used the keyword `lazy` to mean memoized. And this implements the same pattern.

Comment: No, I don't think so. They are orthogonal, aren't they? "lazy" means we don't evaluate for the first time until we are first asked for a value. "memoize" we _do_ evaluate the first time but not after that.

Comment: @matt I think Swift use different term. If you look at iOS's `lazy var`, it has your "memoize" behavior.